# How to concatenate a name of file using fopen function?

Tags: c, fopen, strcat

I want to create  a file with a a prticular extension added after the supplied name.

I create this code:

```
void create_file(char name[],char user[],char date[]){

    FILE* fichier=NULL;
    fichier=fopen(strcat(name,".txt"),"a+");
    fprintf(fichier,"user: %s connected at : %s \n",user,date);
    fclose(fichier);

}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I want to concatenate name with ".txt" I don't get the good solution.I tried to create a new string char ch1[]=strcat(name,".txt") I got an error.

Comment: @arrowman  What error you got ?

Comment: error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘ch1’

Comment: I have to say, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Answer (score 3):

As I can see, there are three issues with your code,

```
fichier=fopen(strcat(name,".txt"),"a+");
fprintf(fichier,"user: %s connected at : %s \n",user,date);
```

namely,

1. You did not check for NULL for `name`. In case it is NULL, `strcat()` will invoke  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. You did not make sure that `name` contains enough memory to hold the concatenated string (maybe need a little more information, as this can *and probably should* be handled from the caller itself). If the destination is not having enough memory, again, you'll face UB.
3. You did not check for the success of `fopen()`. In case `fopen()` fails, you'll passing an invalid pointer to `fprintf()` which will , one again, cause UB.

Any of the above three is *alone* sufficient to make your code fail.

Comment: 1) Why should he check inside that function for null for name ?

2) Why should he check if he has enough memory for name inside that Function ?

I think he will do that check before he's going to pass that "name". maybe my opinion is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On your comment -

```
char ch1[]=strcat(name,".txt");
```

Instead of what you did, try this -

```
const char* name1=".txt";
ch1=malloc(strlen(name)+4+1);  // don't forget to free memory
strcpy(ch1,name);
strcat(ch1,name1);  
fichier=fopen(ch1,"a+");  // also check return of fopen()
```

Comment: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: "char ch1[]=strcat(name,".txt");" it is not ok because of the invalid initializer|

Comment: @Michi Yes that's mistake he did and I replied with solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this should be enough for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void create_file(char *name,char *user,char *date){
    FILE *fichier = fopen(name ,"a+");

    if (fichier == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fichier,"user: %s connected at : %s \n",user,date);
    fclose(fichier);
}

int main(void){
    char *name = "database.txt";
    char *user = "Michi";
    char *date = "14.08.15";

    create_file(name, user, date);

    return 0;
}
```

But if you really need strcat:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void create_file(char *name,char *user,char *date){
    char s[100];
    strcpy(s, name);
    strcat(s, ".txt");

    FILE *fichier = fopen(s ,"a+");

    if (fichier == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fichier,"user: %s connected at : %s \n",user,date);
    fclose(fichier);
}

int main(void){
    char *name = "database";
    char *user = "Michi";
    char *date = "14.08.15";

    create_file(name, user, date);

    return 0;
}
```